# C++ Parallel_For issues

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, c++17

I'm currently writing a genetic algorithm for my dissertation and running into an error implementing a parallel_for loop, its probably very obvious but I'm not sure how to solve the issue.

```
void evaluate_population_fitness(vector<Chromosome *> population) {
  std::for_each(std::execution::par_unseq, population.begin(), population.end(), [](Chromosome *item) {
    item->setLength(1 / calculate_Chromosome_length(item));
  });
}
```

This is the actual parallel for loop here is the function it calls:

```
double calculate_Chromosome_length(Chromosome *path) {
  double sum = 0;
  vector<City *> cities = path->getCities();
  for (int i = 0; i < cities.size()-1; i++) {
    sum += sqrt(pow(cities[i]->getPosX() - cities[i + 1]->getPosX(), 2)
                    + pow(cities[i]->getPosY() - cities[i + 1]->getPosY(), 2));
    cout << sum << std::endl;
  }
  cout << sum << std::endl;
  return sum;
}
```

Unfortunately, this just means it returns all zeroes. whereas it should really compute some euclidean distance.
for reference, Chromosome is a object containing a length of type double and a vector of references to cities `vector<City *>` a City is defined as a X,Y integers and an String ID.
I'd really appreciate some help here.

Here's how cities are generated:

```
std::vector<City *> generate_randomCity(int number_Of_Cities_to_generate) {
  vector<City *> vector = std::vector<City *>();
  if (number_Of_Cities_to_generate == 0) return vector;
  string city_name = "City";
  for (int i = 0; i < number_Of_Cities_to_generate; i++) {
    city_name += std::to_string(i);
    City city = City(city_name, randomNumber(0, 999), randomNumber(0, 999), i);
    vector.emplace_back(&city);
  }
  return vector;
}
```

Comment: I think the error is something to do with the declaration of sum inside the parallel for.

Comment: I'm using the latest MSVC compiler that ships with Visual studio community 2019, I had seen somewhere that it was supported and im not getting any compilation errors.

Comment: I'd guess the issue might be with how `cities` are generated. Are you sure the pointers are valid and pointing to different objects?

Comment: I'll edit the main post to show how cities are generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd run your code under debugger, you'd probably see that all pointers point to the same address. And that address is invalid (though debugger couldn't tell you that).

You create a *local* object `City`, which dies immediately when the current loop iteration finishes. The pointer you stored in vector is invalid.

It generally very rarely makes sense to keep vector of pointers, so it would be best to reorganize your code to return `std::vector<City>` instead.

```
std::vector<City> generate_randomCity(int number_Of_Cities_to_generate) {
  vector<City> vector;
  //if (number_Of_Cities_to_generate == 0) return vector; //unnecessary, loop can run 0 times, no problem with that
  string city_name = "City";
  for (int i = 0; i < number_Of_Cities_to_generate; i++) {
    //city_name += std::to_string(i); //this will add the number forever, so 5th city gets name 'City01234'
    vector.emplace_back(city_name + std::to_string(i), randomNumber(0, 999), randomNumber(0, 999), i);
  }

  return vector;
}
```

If you really don't want to change your code (you should), you need to create objects that will outlive their current scope. This is done with `new`

```
std::vector<City*> generate_randomCity(int number_Of_Cities_to_generate) {
  vector<City*> vector;
  //if (number_Of_Cities_to_generate == 0) return vector; //unnecessary, loop can run 0 times, no problem with that
  string city_name = "City";
  for (int i = 0; i < number_Of_Cities_to_generate; i++) {
    //city_name += std::to_string(i); //this will add the number forever, so 5th city gets name 'City01234'
    City* city = new City(city_name + std::to_string(i), randomNumber(0, 999), randomNumber(0, 999), i);
    vector.emplace_back(city);
  }
  return vector;
}
```

Note that it's your responsibility to release each of these pointers with `delete` when you finish using them.
Make sure you don't have the same mistake with `vector<Chromosome *> population`

Comment: Awesome answer, thanks so much for the help, I'll go through and adjust my code.

Answer (score 0):

You are storing a pointer to a local variable in `std::vector<City*> vector` and that's undefined behaviour.

```
std::vector<City *> generate_randomCity(int number_Of_Cities_to_generate) {
  vector<City *> vector = std::vector<City *>();
  if (number_Of_Cities_to_generate == 0) return vector;
  string city_name = "City";
  for (int i = 0; i < number_Of_Cities_to_generate; i++) {
    city_name += std::to_string(i);
    City city = City(city_name, randomNumber(0, 999), randomNumber(0, 999), i);
    // Storing a pointer to local variable
    vector.emplace_back(&city);
  }
  return vector;
}
```

Simply, create a city on the heap which does not limit the lifetime of the object:

```
City* city = new City(city_name, randomNumber(0, 999), randomNumber(0, 999), i);
vector.push_back(city);
```

Note that you need to delete the `City` object when you no longer need it, and therefore, it would be better to use smart pointers instead of `new`.

Comment: Will definitely look into smart pointers. I'm from Java land, so definitely getting a tad confused but this solved my error. Now getting proper return values. Thank you!